# Issues with mock + multiple exports in the same file on react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-testing

I am using Jest + React Testing Library in my project, and in one of my components, I have a common `index.ts` that exports all the internal components like:

src/components/commonComponents/index.ts:

```
import A, { IAProps as AType } from './components/A';
import B, { IBProps as BType } from './components/B';
import { C, commonFunc } from './components/Shared';

export type IAProps = AType;
export type IBProps = BType;

export { A, B, C, commonFunc };
```

And I have a component making use of that like:

src/mainComponent:

```
import { A, commonFunc } from 'components/commonComponents';
```

I am trying to test `mainComponent`, as can be seen on top, I need to import 2 of the components being exported in the same index.

I mocked all redux selectors so that, I wouldn't have issues with it. But for some reason the import on top, makes react-testing-library to give me an error on redux (a-if I missed mocking a function) **on component B** that I am not using anywhere and therefore also not mocking anything for that. But if I changed the above import to something like:

```
import A from 'components/commonComponents/components/A';
import { commonFunc } from 'components/commonComponents/components/Shared';
```

I don't get the error anymore...

Any idea what can I do? I can't change all my components to be imported directly from each main file since sometimes I wrap my component with HOC in the index, and they will be needed in future tests...

Comment: Any luck with this. I have a similar issue where the mocked component is not accessing imported variables.